# Component typing react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

#### Scenario:

I create the Text component; another Tag component is embedded in it.

#### Question:

How can I type it to make it work? Now an error appears and it does not accept the desired styles.

#### The error is this:

```
Type '{ children: ReactNode; classNames: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

#### This is my code:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import styles from './Text.module.css';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';

const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

interface ITextProps {
    variant: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6' | 'p1' | 'p2' | 'p3';
    bold?: boolean;
}

const tags = {
    h1: 'h1',
    h2: 'h2',
    h3: 'h3',
    h4: 'h4',
    h5: 'h5',
    h6: 'h6',
    p1: 'p',
    p2: 'p',
    p3: 'p',
};

const Text: React.FC<ITextProps> = ({ children, variant, bold }) => {
    const Tag = tags[variant];

    return <Tag classNames={cx({ title: variant === 'h1' })}>{children}</Tag>;
};

export default Text;
```

Comment: Now I'm trying to change my code based on your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

> Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either
>   - **a tag name string** (such as `'div'` or `'span'`),
>   - a React component type (a class or a function),
>   - or a React fragment type.

```
const Template = React.createElement(tags[variant], {}, children);
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const tags = {
    h1: "h1",
    h2: "h2",
    h3: "h3",
    h4: "h4",
    h5: "h5",
    h6: "h6",
    p1: "p",
    p2: "p",
    p3: "p"
  };
  const Template = React.createElement(tags['h1'], {}, 'Text');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {Template}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did it:
const Text: React.FC<ITextProps> = ({ children, variant, bold }) => {
    const Tag = React.createElement(tags[variant], {}, children);

    return <React.Fragment>{Tag}</React.Fragment>;
};

Comment: But I do not understand if I want to use different classes depending on the props in the parent element using the library classNames/bind

Comment: example:
classNames={cx({ title: variant === 'h1', description: variant === 'p1'  })}

Comment: @MaxAkinshin Pass it to the second params, it receives the props

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a type declaration for children to your interface to get rid of this error. The correct type for children is React.ReactNode -  try modifying your interface to this...

```
interface ITextProps {
 children: React.ReactNode
 variant: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'h3' | 'h4' | 'h5' | 'h6' | 'p1' | 'p2' | 'p3';
 bold?: boolean;
}
```