# Creating heading element using props in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

New to TS, so working on implementing it on a project. Don't know what this is called so can't search for it correctly. If someone has the term for it then I will change the title.

What I am trying to do is pass the `size` prop into my component and use that to create the correct HTML element. e.g. `size="h3"` would create a `<h3>` element.

```
import React from "react";

import styles from "./Header.module.css";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  containerStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
  id: string;
  size?: string;
  title?: string;
  titleStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
}

export default function Header({
  children,
  containerStyle,
  id,
  size = "h3",
  title,
  titleStyle,
}: Props) {
  const HeadingTag = size;
  return (
    <div className={styles.headerContainer} style={containerStyle}>
      <HeadingTag className={styles.header} style={titleStyle} id={id}>
        {title}
      </HeadingTag>
      <div className={styles.close}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}`
```

The error I am getting is:

> TS2322: Type '{ children: string | undefined; className: any; style: CSSProperties | undefined; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.|   Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force a component property to be an h2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71269888/force-a-component-property-to-be-an-h2)

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205988/component-typing-react-typescript

Comment: No, instead of trying to mark this one as a duplicate, you should suggest a title change to make those more searchable for "Creating an element"

Comment: Oh, dont get me wrong please, second question i posted is almost exactly about what you were asking, accepted answer - also as i see. Btw your question is googled nice with "react prop h2 typescript". And i do that only for 1 purpose - to help you find what you are asking, some more details. And duplcates, really, that question very popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [React.createElement()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

```
import React from "react";

import styles from "./Header.module.css";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  containerStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
  id: string;
  size?: string;
  title?: string;
  titleStyle?: React.CSSProperties;
}

export default function Header({
  children,
  containerStyle,
  id,
  size = "h3",
  title,
  titleStyle,
}: Props) {
  const HeadingTag = React.createElement(size, { className: styles.header, style: titleStyle, id }, title);

  return (
    <div className={styles.headerContainer} style={containerStyle}>
      {HeadingTag}
      <div className={styles.close}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Other Examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: This is a great answer, but I do wonder *why* this works? I guess because we are able to use the prop `size` as a string until the inner component is created? So essentially the `string` type is correct on the `Header` component but also able to cast into the new component. Ok. Rubber duck I think got it.

Comment: when you write <h3> or any valid JSX code, react will convert/transpile to `createElement( ...`  . But size is a JS string not JSX syntax so it fails to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to cast and render a string `"h3"` as a jsx object, which will naturally produce errors.
One thing you could do to acheive this goal is to use multiple types, containing your size options as actual jsx elements, just type:

```
TextSize: h1 | h2 | h3 | ...
```

That way you ensure that only certain specific valid types can be inserted, and you can simply render the element in your component.

```
<TextSize>{title}</Textsize>
```

Comment: Do you suggest add `TextSize: h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6;` as a type in the list of types? Because TS says it cannot find `h1` so I assume I am doing it wrong. Specifically the error is: `type h6 = /*unresolved*/ any
Cannot find name 'h6'.ts(2304)` Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Weird, it was working on different jsx elements as far as i remember, maybe not the default html tags like h1 or p. I'll check into it. You can alternatively render a component with the string size property, using react's ```createElement``` method. Like @bogdanoff mentioned below me